# MVC and Angularjs : promise does not waiting data

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

i'm newby in angularjs i researched on the internet but i couldn't find any suitable solution for my problem. I made an http call to get some data from controller. The controller side is okay. But the client-side, promise does not waiting data. Here codes that I wrote ;

```
//service code 
angular.module("myApp").service('$myService', function ($http, $q) {
            this.getDataArray = function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('../Home/GetDataArray')
                    .success(function success(response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                        console.log("error getting data array");
                        deferred.reject();
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            };
    }

// controller-code
angular.module("myApp").controller('dataController', function ($scope, $http, $myService) {

        $scope.getDataFromService = function () {
            $myService.getDataArray().then(function (response) {
                    $scope.dataArray = response.data;
                });
        };
    });
}
```

When i call the getDataFromService method at first $scope.dataArray is empty, but the second call, $scope.dataArray is filled with data. Where is the problem? Thanks for helps.

Comment: can you check the result of the first HTTP call in fiddler/chrome dev tools?

Comment: I also checked it, but when i made first call, $scope.dataArray is empty because promise does not wait as i said

Comment: I don't mean $scope.data, I mean the HTTP call itself. Are you absolutely sure the response of the first call (as seen in Chrome dev tools) contains data?

Comment: Nope, the first call does not contains data.

Comment: Well, if the first call does not contain data, the problem is at the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an angular expert myself. This is just how I did it when I ran into the same problem. Try this:

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('dataController',[ '$scope', 'Service1', '$http', function ($scope, Service1, $http) {
    var deferred = Service1.getDataArray().$promise;
            return deferred.then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                $scope.dataArray = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            })
    }])
```

and service:

```
   var service = angular.module("myApp").service('myService', ['ngResource']);
  myService.factory('Service1', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return $resource('../Home/GetDataArray', {}, {
          get: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
      });
  }])
```

The idea is that your service isn't the one that should wait for a return, your controller is. So you should wait for the promise in your controller not your service. In my example I am using factories because, well, that's how I got around it in my project, you can try and implement this directly if you don't want to use a factory.